# How do I use a @Transformer bean with Spring Integration Java DSL?

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

I'd like to use a bean with a method annotated with @Transformer to transform a message accessing part of its headers with the @Header annotation. Is there a way to do this with the Java DSL (with Java 7, so no lambdas)? It does not seem like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.handle("myTransformer", "myMethod")
```

if your transformer doesn't return `Message`.

From other side, if you already use `@Transformer` there you can add `channel` attributes to make the real endpoint for that method and use those channels from the `IntegrationFlow`, e.g. `.gateway("transformChannel")`

Since 1.1 we are going to add more EIP-methods to make it more flexible for similar cases.

Feel free to raise [GH issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues) on the matter!

Comment: Accepted this answer since I believe it matches what I expected from the JAVa DSL more then the other. It would be nice to have a .transform(myTransformerBean()) method though, waiting to see how 1.1 will offer in this regard. Thank you in any case! :)

Comment: Oh, and I just send a Pull Request to add an overload of the .filter("") SpEL filtering method.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
.transform("@transformerBean.someMethod(payload, headers['foo'])")
```

...should work.